# How to fix "TypeError: must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper" error in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python and was trying to make a small program to record changes in money. When I try and use information stored in the file 'amount.txt' an error occurs and states 'TypeError: must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper' How can I fix this and still use the data from 'amount.txt'?

```
dollars = open("Amount.txt", "r")
print("Current Updated Total: ($" + dollars + ")")
                                    ^This is where the problem occurs
```

I expect the output to state 'Current Updated Total: ($100)'
The actual output however is 'TypeError: must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: I would suggest opening files inside a `with` block which automatically handles closing the file when you are done working with it. Docs can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, you just need to read the contents of the file:

```
dollars = open("Amount.txt", "r").read()
```

The result of just `open()` is a file object, `_io.TextIOWrapper`; it services a container for doing different types of operations on the file in addition to reading its entire contents as you want to do in this case.

Also, in Python 3, `"r"` is the default mode, so you can just use:

```
dollars = open("Amount.txt").read()
```